# Master Page label control not keeping value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have an AJAX Extender Calendar control on my master page.  When I fire the selection changed event (below) it pulls back the information and then displays it to the label control, however when navigating to a different page in the site it loses the information.

I have tried putting it into a session variable too but on postback it says that the values are null.

the code is

```
 protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var CalendarParam = new SqlParameter("@G_DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        CalendarParam.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

        var CalendarParamNextDay = new SqlParameter("@G_DateTimePlusOneDay", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        CalendarParamNextDay.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1);

        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection
            (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IslandersDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(CalendarParam);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(CalendarParamNextDay);
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "fixtures.GetGameDetails";
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn;
            sqlconn.Open();
            //SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            using(SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sqlda.Fill(dt);

                foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    GetOpponenet go = new GetOpponenet();
                    go.GameDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]);
                    go.Opponenet = dr[1].ToString();
                    go.Location = dr[2].ToString();

                    string location = go.Location ;
                    string opponent = go.Opponenet;
                    DateTime GameDate = go.GameDate; ;

                    lblGameDate.Text = GameDate.ToString();
                    lblLocation.Text = location;
                    lblOponenet.Text = opponent;

                 }
            }

        }

    }
```

any and all help massively appreciated

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Islanders.master.cs" Inherits="cs_ASP_Islanders.Islanders" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Peterborough Islanders</title>
    <link href="_CSS/Islanders-Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="_CSS/StickyFooter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <meta name="description" content="Peterborough Islanders NIHL Ice Hockey Club" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv(ticket_sale) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(ticket_sale).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }
        </script>


</head>
<body class="BackGround">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrap">

    <div id="main">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                      </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="Main">
            <div class="Header">
                <img src="_images/PageBasics/Logo.fw.png" class="Logo" alt="Peterborough Islanders" />
                <img src="_images/PageBasics/billboard.fw.png" class="BillBoard" alt="Next Game" />
            </div>
            <div class="Body">
                <div class="Links">
                        <a href="Default.aspx"><img src="_images/PageBasics/News.fw.png" border="0" height="46px" width="137px"   alt="News"/></a>
                        <a href="Contact.aspx"><img src="_images/PageBasics/Contact.fw.png" border="0"  height="46px" width="137px" alt="Contact Us" class="HeaderLink"/></a>
                        <a href="Fixtures.aspx"><img src="_images/PageBasics/Fixtures.fw.png" border="0"  height="46px" width="137px"   alt="Fixtures and Results" class="HeaderLink"/></a>
                        <a href="Gallery.aspx"><img src="_images/PageBasics/Gallery.fw.png" border="0"  height="46px" width="137px"   alt="Gallery" class="HeaderLink"/></a>
                        <a href="Roster.aspx"><img src="_images/PageBasics/Roster.fw.png" border="0"  height="46px" width="137px"   alt="Roster" class="HeaderLink"/></a>
                        <a href="Sponsorship.aspx"><img src="_images/PageBasics/Sponsors.fw.png" border="0"  height="46px" width="137px"  alt="Sponsors" class="HeaderLink"/></a>
                        <a href="Stats.aspx"><img src="_images/PageBasics/Stats.fw.png" border="0"  height="46px" width="137px"   alt="Stats" class="HeaderLink"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="PageLeft">
                   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="body" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


                   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SubBody" runat="server" >
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div> 

                <div class="PageRight">
                    <div class="RightContent" style="Display:none">
                        <p>Last Game</p>
                            <img src="_images/OpponentLogo/IslandersGameIcon.fw.png" alt="Home Team" />
                               -V-
                            <img alt="" src="_images/OpponentLogo/CardiffDevilsLogo.png" height="102" width ="124"/>
                            <table width="295" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="195px">Teams</td>
                                    <td width="25px">1</td>
                                    <td width="25px">2</td>
                                    <td width="25px">3</td>
                                    <td width="25px">F</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Peterborugh Islanders</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Cardiff Devils</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="RightContent">

                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                                        BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="1" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                                        Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="250px" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" 
                                        Width="300px" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender" 
                                            onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged1">
                                        <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" 
                                        Height="8pt" />
                                        <DayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                                        <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#000000" />
                                        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#646473" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold ="True" />
                                        <TitleStyle BackColor="#000000" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" 
                                        Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="White" Height="12pt" />
                                        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#000000" ForeColor="White" />
                                        </asp:Calendar>
                                    <%--</ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
                                Blue = Home Game <br />
                                Orange = Away Game
                                <br /><br />

                                <div class="calendarGameInfo">
                                Game Date :<asp:Label ID="lblGameDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
                                Location :<asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
                                Opponent :<asp:Label ID="lblOponenet" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                                <div class="RightContent">
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BasketCounter" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Panel ID="basket_panel" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="110%">
                                        <div class="basket">
                                            <div class="cart-count">
                                                <span class="counter">
                                                <img src="_images/Stack.png" class="ion-bag" />
                                                <%--<b id="order_counter" runat="server">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                </b>--%></span><span class="info-link"><a href="Checkout.aspx">Go to My Basket &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                                                    </div>
                    <img src="_images/PageBasics/facebook.png" class="FaceBook" alt="Join Us on Facebook" />
                    <p>Proud to be working with</p>
                    <img src="_images/PageBasics/phantoms.fw.png" alt="Peterborough Phantoms" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div> 


    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
 <div class="Sponsors">
 <img src="_images/PageBasics/LineDivide.fw.png" alt="" />
 <p>Proudly supported by: </p>
 <br/>
    <img src="_images/Sponsors/_logo-h87.fw.png" alt="" class="SponsorImage"/>
    <img src="_images/Sponsors/officialclubnights.png" alt="Offical Club Night Out" class="SponsorImage" />
 <br />
    <img src="_images/Sponsors/RedLionBourne_logo.png" alt="The Red Lion - Bourne" class="SponsorImage" />
    <img src="_images/Sponsors/PlanetIceSmall.fw.png" alt="Planet Ice Peterborough" class="SponsorImage" /> 
    <img src="_images/Sponsors/SiNET.fw.png" alt="Website hosted by SiNET Development" />

 </div>
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace cs_ASP_Islanders
{
    public partial class Islanders : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public DataTable GetDates()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IslandersDB"].ConnectionString);
            {
                sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn;

                try
                {
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    sqlcmd.CommandText = "select f.hometeam, f.awayteam, f.GameDateandTime, f.location from fixtures.fixtures f";
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
                    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                {
                    string msg = "Fetch Error:";
                    msg += ex.Message;
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                }
                finally
                {
                    sqlconn.Close();
                }

                return dt;
            }
        }

        protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = GetDates();
                DateTime eventDate;
                string eventType = string.Empty;

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Where ColumnFieldForDate and ColumnFieldForEventType are the field names from your database
                        eventDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["GameDateandTime"]);
                        eventType = dt.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString();


                        if (e.Day.Date == eventDate.Date)
                        {
                            if (eventType == "Peterborough")
                            {
                                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SkyBlue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var CalendarParam = new SqlParameter("@G_DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            CalendarParam.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

            var CalendarParamNextDay = new SqlParameter("@G_DateTimePlusOneDay", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            CalendarParamNextDay.Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1);

            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection
                (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IslandersDB"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(CalendarParam);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(CalendarParamNextDay);
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "fixtures.GetGameDetails";
                sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn;
                sqlconn.Open();
                //SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                using(SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sqlda.Fill(dt);

                    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        GetOpponenet go = new GetOpponenet();
                        go.GameDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]);
                        go.Opponenet = dr[1].ToString();
                        go.Location = dr[2].ToString();

                        string location = go.Location ;
                        string opponent = go.Opponenet;
                        DateTime GameDate = go.GameDate; ;

                        lblGameDate.Text = GameDate.ToString();
                        lblLocation.Text = location;
                        lblOponenet.Text = opponent;

                      }
                }

            }

        }


        //private void check_cart()
        //{
        //    //if (Session["cart_counter"] == null)
        //    //{
        //    //    order_counter.InnerText = "0";


        //    //}
        //    //else
        //    //{
        //    //    basket_panel.Visible = true;
        //    //    order_counter.InnerText = Convert.ToString(Session["cart_counter"]);
        //    //}
        //}


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your master page? Do you have view state enabled?

Comment: I will edit the question with the entire master page code and code behind.

Comment: i have edited the question to show my master page, ive not used view state before.... will look into it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I was doing it correctly by using sessions, however I needed to get the information in the Page_PreRender

```
      protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["Date"] != null)
        {
        string opponent = (string)Session["Opponent"];
        string location = (string)Session["Location"];
        DateTime GameDate = (DateTime)Session["Date"];
        //DateTime CalendarDate = (DateTime)Session["Calendar"];
        lblOponenet.Text = opponent;
        lblLocation.Text = location;
        lblGameDate.Text = GameDate.ToString();           

        }

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```